# Como funciona o Google Analytics

Tags: google, front-end, google-analytics-api

Como o Google Analytics consegue verificar a origem do clique?
Como a API sabe as palavras chaves que originaram a pesquisa Google (cujo chegou até o site)?

Essas dúvidas me perseguem a anos.
Se alguém conseguir algum artigo sobre a documentação eu ficaria imensamente agradecido.

Forte abraço.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Esta resposta é muito longa, mas aí vai meus 2 centavos do que aprendi até hoje observando o Google:

**1. Como o Google sabe quais palavras chaves de busca levaram o usuário até o site?**

Repare que quando você faz uma busca no Google, os links para os sites encontrados constam como os links reais (por exemplo, se a busca foi por `StackOverflow`, o primeiro resultado aponta para `www.stackoverflow.com`).

Porém, em cada âncora (`a`) existe um callback registrado para o evento `onmousedown`. Este evento substitui o `href` da âncora por um `href` que aponta para os servidores do Google, e este por sua vez redireciona o browser para o site real. Veja as imagens abaixo:

*Antes de clickar*

[image: Antes de clickar no link]

*Após clickar no link*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deste modo, o Google associa as palavras chaves digitadas, com o site digitado, e pode utilizar esta informação para otimizar os resultados de busca (vale notar, que o Google oferece resultados de buscas de acordo com o padrão de visitação também, sendo este rastreado através da sua conta Google (acredito que o Chrome envie dados do histórico para o Google também, mas não pare para analisar)).

*Edição*:

Repare na no valor do `href` após a execução do evento `onmousedown`, que o novo valor do `href` não inclui o endereço do site real (`www.stackoverflow.com`). Isto indica que algum dos parâmetros da query identifica unicamente a URL real dentro do servidor do Google no contexto da busca. Assim, o Google consegue rastrear que as palavras chaves digitadas, estão realmente relacionadas com a URL, e pode melhorar seus resultados de busca na próxima iteração do algorítmo de classificação.

Um outro ponto menos técnico, mas que também justifica que o Google armazene a busca e os resultados em sua base de dados de maneira referenciável, é que se não o fosse, seria possível que um concorrente adulterasse as URL's finais, degradando as estatísticas utilizadas pelo Google no page ranking. Exemplo:

Imagine que no `href`, após o `onmousedown`, o Google tenha colocado para o `StackOverflow` algo como `/url?keyword=stackoverflow&real=www.stackoverflow.com`. Isso significa que quando o usuário clickar no link, o Google será informado que a keyword digitada foi `stackoverflow` e o site real é o `www.stackoverflow.com`.

Agora imagine por exemplo um vírus no computador do cliente (ou um ataque de MITM), alterando a URL para: `/url?keyword=aumente%20seu&url=www.stackoverflow.com`. Quando o usuário clickar neste link, o Google ficará sabendo que as keywords `aumente seu` estão relacionadas com `www.stackoverflow.com`, degradando a performance do page ranking.

Isto poderia ser feito não apenas por concorrentes, mas também por Trolls e pessoas que querem fazer seu site aparecer no topo das pesquisas.

**2. Como o Google Analytics consegue verificar a origem do clique?**

Quando o código do Analytics é executado na página visitada, ele coleta informações do browser e do sistema. Visitando o site [www.nortonconsultoria.com.br](http://www.nortonconsultoria.com.br), foram estas as informações coletadas e enviadas através de parâmetros GET para o Anlytics:

```
utmwv:5.6.2
utms:1
utmn:1342588638
utmhn:www.nortonconsultoria.com.br
utmcs:UTF-8
utmsr:1280x1024
utmvp:1265x716
utmsc:24-bit
utmul:en-us
utmje:1
utmfl:-
utmdt:Norton TI
utmhid:952692061
utmr:-
utmp:/
utmht:1423077254452
utmac:UA-41756695-1
utmcc:__utma=223515140.1707534080.1422473707.1422473707.1423077254.2;+__utmz=223515140.1422473707.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);
utmjid:986782225
utmredir:1
utmu:qAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE~
```

Além destas informações, o header HTTP envia outras, em especial o `User-Agent`, utilizado para exibir quais as plataformas mais incidem no seu site.

Acredito que existam meios mais complexos do Google coletar outras informações, mas desconheço. Estes são apenas dados que notei que são enviados para o Google através das ferramentas de desenvolvedor do Chrome (olhei no Firefox também para ver se haviam grandes diferenças, mas não encontrei nada).

Espero que tenha ajudado um pouco!

Comment: Muito bom seu comentário.
Então no caso, o Analytics busca as informações de palavras chaves direto na base do Google?
Ou tem outro meio de buscar os termos correspondidos ao link?

Comment: Comecei a responder aqui nos comentários, mas acabei reparando mais coisas, e achei melhor incluir na resposta.

Comment: Certo, sendo assim, não tem como saber qual a palavra chave que resultou a pesquisa se não o próprio Google.